# How to design a program (structure and literal file/folder structure) for the real world? (Specifically C#)

Tags: c#, oop, project-management

How would one create, or where could one find an example of a relatively simple C# program that is big enough to require multiple classes and files and demonstrate medium complexity of OOP based interactions?

Some examples would be great.

There are a lot of resources out there, and I am familiar with OOP syntax and concepts, but is seems that there are few resources that take a step back and look at the bigger picture, or so it seems.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

[Tree Surgeon](http://www.codeplex.com/treesurgeon)

SO Questions:

- [Project Structure for C# Development Effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789389/project-structure-for-c-development-effort)
- [What’s a good directory structure for large C#/C++ solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280439/whats-a-good-directory-structure-for-large-c-c-solutions)

Answer (score -1):

A relatively simple, yet complete project that showcases ASP.NET MVC is [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Don't think this is a good example, it is just a single relatively small website, the MVC don't need areas and there is only a single project in the solution.